# How to run wxWidgets applications on other machines?

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets

I have downloaded wxWidgets-3.1.0.zip and extracted it to `D:\wxWidgets-3.1.0`. MY OS: Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit. I am using visual Studio 2015.

I build the library through running: `D:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\build\msw\wx_vc14.sln`, It was OK. So I can build the projects in `samples`.

- The thing that matters I cannot run this application on another machines where wxWidgets is not installed there. I Don't know Which `dlls` I must Copy side-by-side my application.
- How Can I Also build `statically` my application so I don not have to copy `Dlls`?
- Can any one add a useful tutorial step by step on how to build on both: `Static` and `dynamic`?.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the D:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\samples\minimal\minimal.sln you will be able to see what options you should set. Also, by default, the solution is set to build statically build executable. You can also try to change the "C/C++ -> Code Generation -> RunTime library" in order to statically link the CRT.

If you still need/want the DLL build, at the very least you will need "base" and "core" libraries from D:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\vc_dll folder. And you will also need the CRT libraries. Every time you run the binary, you will get an error on screen that "library such-and-such can't be found". Just copy the library to the same folder where the executable is located.

The other thing - you should've build the library with "Build->Batch Build...->Select All->Build".

HTH.

Comment: Where Can I find `CRT libraries`?

Comment: @Lacrymosa7, the same way - you just run the program and see what error message will be produced. Then you will need to copy those libraries over. Or just use the install generator to add them to the project. You can also use Dependancy Walker for that but that way will be slower.

Comment: It worked for me: I run the application on another computer, I read the error message about missing dlls and each time I add the required dll. But What about static linking I do not have a clue on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

MSVS 2015 doesn't support linking CRT statically any longer, so you will need to install its CRT DLLs on the target machine in some way. It could be as simple as just copying the DLLs to your application folder (although this is not recommended by Microsoft), but it still needs to be done.

You can build wxWidgets statically simply by choosing the "Release" configuration in the solution file (and not the "DLL Release" one).

Comment: Thank you!. "It could be as simple as just copying the DLLs to your application folder (although this is not recommended by Microsoft" What's the alternative? And is there a helpful link?

Comment: The alternative is to run the redist CRT installer to install the DLLs globally if they're not installed yet. The exact way to do it depends on how you install your program, e.g. if you use MSI or not.